# how to convert multiple html files to excel xlsx files

Tags: python, html, excel, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

a = "/Users/abhijitchavan/Desktop/yes/SearchResult1.xls"
tables = pd.read_html(a)
table = tables[0]

print(table)

table.to_excel('/Users/abhijitchavan/Desktop/yes/dd.xlsx')

THE ABOVE CODE WORKES PERFECT, BUT IT CONVERTS ONLY ONE FILE AT A TIME, HOW CAN I INPUT MULTIPLE FILES AND CONVERT THEM AT SAME TIME

(FILE EXTENSION IS .XLS BUT THOSE FILE ARE HTML FILES)
```

THE ABOVE CODE WORKES PERFECT, BUT IT CONVERTS ONLY ONE FILE AT A TIME, HOW CAN I INPUT MULTIPLE FILES AND CONVERT THEM AT SAME TIME

(FILE EXTENSION IS .XLS BUT THOSE FILE ARE HTML FILES)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
files = ["/Users/abhijitchavan/Desktop/yes/SearchResult1.xls","/Users/abhijitchavan/Desktop/yes/SearchResult2.xls"]
for i in range(0,len(files)):
    a=files[i]
    tables = pd.read_html(a)
    table = tables[0]
    print(table)
    table.to_excel('/Users/abhijitchavan/Desktop/yes/dd"+str(i)+".xlsx')
```

Comment: The code works , but i just want to declare folder, not all File names in the code. say suppose there are 10 files in the folder, i want output as 10 files in xlsx format